# How to get authKey value from this object using php

Tags: php, json

> SME\AuthKeyTransactionResponse Object (
>   [authKey:SME\AuthKeyResponse:private] =>
>   f45c0309-85a5-433c-8bd1-0d681e8cdf40
>   [apiResponse:SME\Response:private] => SME\APIResponse Object (
>   [responseCode:SME\APIResponse:private] => 0
>   [responseText:SME\APIResponse:private] => Success ) )

how to get this value: **f45c0309-85a5-433c-8bd1-0d681e8cdf40** using php

Comment: Instead of `print_r()`, try to iterate over the object with `foreach($class as $key => $value) { print "$key => $value\n"; }` . See if that gives more useful info.

Comment: return nothing.

Comment: What methods does the corresponding Class have? Is there are getter for the field `authKey`?

Comment: yes i found function "getAuthKey"